# ESC and Caps Lock get swapped to original mapping after loading bashrc twice

Tags: bash, vim

I followed xmodmap way of swapping ESC and Caps lock in [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows). It works well when I load .bashrc with `. ~/.bashrc` for the first time. However, if I edit different part of my .bashrc and reload it with same command, two keys are swapped back to original mapping. Why is this happening?

Portion of my .bashrc file

```
...
xmodmap ~/.speedswapper
...
```

My ~/.speedswapper script

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `~/.bashrc` is called every time you open a new terminal. You should put `xmodmap ~/.speedswapper` to some file that is executed once you log into your machine. I prefer to have it present in `~/.xinitrc`

A better way would be to put the swap code under `~/.Xmodmap` which is executed correctly. But it has always been flaky to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I placed the codes in `~/.Xmodmap`, and it's working like charm. I still don't get why .bashrc getting loaded twice resets the swap...I'm fairly new to bash...

Comment: @kidonchu Because that code is executed on second load as well. If you load `.bashrc` again, it'll swap those keys again. Try loading it three times.